# Flask JWT Extended module not found error

Tags: python, flask

Module import error 'flask.typing' when trying to import from Flask-JWT-Extended.

Tried running below command after doing, pip install Flask-JWT-Extended

```
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token, get_jwt_identity
```

Getting following error,

```
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token, get_jwt_identity
[autoreload of flask_jwt_extended.exceptions failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 257, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 455, in superreload
    module = reload(module)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 159, in reload
    raise ImportError(msg.format(parent_name),
ImportError: parent 'flask_jwt_extended' not in sys.modules
]
[autoreload of flask_jwt_extended.internal_utils failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 257, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 455, in superreload
    module = reload(module)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 159, in reload
    raise ImportError(msg.format(parent_name),
ImportError: parent 'flask_jwt_extended' not in sys.modules
]
[autoreload of flask_jwt_extended.typing failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 257, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 455, in superreload
    module = reload(module)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 159, in reload
    raise ImportError(msg.format(parent_name),
ImportError: parent 'flask_jwt_extended' not in sys.modules
]
[autoreload of flask_jwt_extended.config failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 257, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 455, in superreload
    module = reload(module)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 159, in reload
    raise ImportError(msg.format(parent_name),
ImportError: parent 'flask_jwt_extended' not in sys.modules
]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [7] in <cell line: 1>
    from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token, get_jwt_identity

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask_jwt_extended\__init__.py:1 in <module>
    from .jwt_manager import JWTManager as JWTManager

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask_jwt_extended\jwt_manager.py:16 in <module>
    from flask_jwt_extended.default_callbacks import default_additional_claims_callback

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask_jwt_extended\default_callbacks.py:13 in <module>
    from flask.typing import ResponseReturnValue

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.typing'
```

Comment: Which flask version are you using?